# Importing GIT branch projects into IDE

Tags: git, svn, branch

I was working until now with SVN (version control system) but now i am migrating to GIT.
There are some topics that i am experience difficulties , for example in the branch topic,
my company ever time a new feature(release) was started , we create a branch in SVN repository and then we checkout this branch to our local machine and import that in Eclipse.

But with GIT i think the branches are just "logical" pointers , they are not a full copy of the master or the Trunk(in the SVN case).When we clone a repository , the process clones all the repository.So my question is : How can i import in Eclipse just the Git Branch ? LIke i was doing in SVN, probably i am missing something here , but i am new to GIT.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Branches in Subversion are also "logical pointers" aka "cheap copies". Therefore it is unclear what's your question.

Answer (score 0):

In svn, when you checkout the feature branch you get "the project", right? All the files and stuff for that specific branch. In git, you will get the same thing..... except that all the other branches will be "hidden" behind that single branch that you work on (the branch that is checked out). With svn for every branch you wanted to work on, you created a new directory that was a working copy of the svn branch. Now in git all the branches will be accesible through that single working *tree* that you set up when you cloned the git repo.

Comment: Git's equivalent of SVN directory-per-branch is [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).